# Iterate through array and choose based on priority

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

First post here!

Ok.. I have a contact XML as follows:

```
<contact>
  <item>
    <ContactData type="String">+4444444444</ContactData>
    <Type type="String">1</Type>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ContactData type="String">+9999999999</ContactData>
    <Type type="String">3</Type>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ContactData type="String">anyone123452154@gmail.com</ContactData>
    <Type type="String">4</Type>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ContactData type="String">+5554444444</ContactData>
    <Type type="String">2</Type>
  </item>
</contact>
```

As you can see type 4 is an e-mail, type 1 is a telephone number, type 2 is a fax and type 3 is a mobile number.

So here's my scenario:

I (probably) need to iterate through all these nodes. Check to see if there is a telephone number (highest priority) and choose it. If there's no telephone number we need to check for mobile number (second highest priority). If mobile number is not available we choose e-mail (or we do nothing). How can I achieve it?

Thanks..

Comment: There is no point in using CDATA sections in a posted question. It's just not pertinent to the actual problem, and it obscures without any benefit. I will help with an edit.

Comment: not sure where to write this... but you GUYS ARE AWESOME!!!.. thank you very much..!! I appreciate it... I used the solution from Tim C..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be to simply iterate over the **item** elements with an **xsl:for-each**, with a sort on the value of the **Type** element. Then you can simply pick the first element.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="contact">
      <xsl:for-each select="item[ContactData != '']">
         <xsl:sort select="Type" order="ascending" />
         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="ContactData" />
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
+4444444444
```

If you were to blank out the phone number, it should return the mobile number instead. Blank that out too, and the email address is returned.

EDIT: If you need to exclude the fax number, you could change the **xsl:for-each** to the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[Type != '2'][ContactData != '']">
```

Or if you wanted to explicity state only phone, mobile or email, then you could do the following

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[Type = '1' or Type = '3' or Type = '4'][ContactData != '']">
```

Comment: Ok.. thanks for your answer.. but I also have a fax with Type '2'... what than? So to be more specific I want only to check for telephone and mobile and choose based on the highest priority..

Comment: Well, it always helps to mention such things in your question! If you could edit your question with the full details, then I am sure it will be easier to expand the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Tim C's answer, but with the additional requirement of only returning Type 1, Type 3, or Type 4 items.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="contact">
        <xsl:variable name="vContacts">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[Type='1' or Type='3' or Type='4']">
                <xsl:sort select="Type"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>                          
        </xsl:variable>
        <results><xsl:value-of select="$vContacts/item[1]/ContactData"/></results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results>+4444444444</results>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This can be obtained with a single XPath expression -- you really don't need XSLT at all**:

```
  ( /*/item[Type = 1]
   |
    /*[not(item[Type = 1])]/item[Type = 3]
   |
    /*[not(item[Type = 1 or Type = 3])]/item[Type = 4]
    )
     /ContactData/text()
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "(/*/item[Type = 1]
   |
    /*[not(item[Type = 1])]/item[Type = 3]
   |
    /*[not(item[Type = 1 or Type = 3])]/item[Type = 4]
    )
     /ContactData/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<contact>
  <item>
    <ContactData type="String">+4444444444</ContactData>
    <Type type="String">1</Type>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ContactData type="String">+9999999999</ContactData>
    <Type type="String">3</Type>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ContactData type="String">anyone123452154@gmail.com</ContactData>
    <Type type="String">4</Type>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ContactData type="String">+5554444444</ContactData>
    <Type type="String">2</Type>
  </item>
</contact>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected node(s) is copied to the output:**

```
+4444444444
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you have XPath 2.0, you can write the types you want in the order of their priority as `(1,3,4)`, iterate over the types and choose the first one that is there:

```
/contact/(for $i in (1,3,4) return item[Type = $i])[1]/ContactData/text()
```

Or with an unrolled loop:

```
/contact/(*[Type = 1], *[Type = 3], *[Type = 4])[1]/ContactData/text()
```